# Maximum product ascending sub sequence

Tags: arrays, algorithm, integer

How to find maximum product ascending sub sequence of size k in an (non negative) integer array  of size n. I did not find any good solution. The sub sequence need not be contiguous. For ex: 3,7,8 in 10,1,3,9,7,8,5 for size 3.

Comment: This looks like hw. Please describe what you've tried already.

Comment: Its not a hw. I was just looking at some interview questions and came across this one.

Comment: My apologies, it would still be nice to see what you've tried so that we can help guide you to the solution from your current method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reducing to a problem you've seen before.

1. Solve the max length increasing subsequence problem.
2. Solve max sum increasing subsequence problem.
3. Think about how a product can be converted to a sum. (hint: logarithm, why?)
4. Solve max product increasing subsequence problem.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to figure out what's going on in your answer, but +1 for a good idea. 3. Hint part 2 - `log ab = log a + log b`.

Comment: In general I think its important to show a general strategy to attack seemingly hard problems. One technique to try is reducing to a problem you've seen before. I think max length increasing subsequence is a canonical dynamic programming problem. So first you must know how to do it (since you'll need the general dynamic programming strategy). Then you can make it trickier by solving max sum increasing subsequence problem. Then once you note #3, you realize that your problem just reduces to #2. Also #3 was the log trick you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, you could do this, although it may not be very fast for large n:

```
import Data.List (maximumBy, sort, subsequences)

maxSubProduct k = 
  maximumBy (\a b -> compare (foldr (*) 1 a) (foldr (*) 1 b)) 
  . filter (\x -> x == sort x) 
  . filter ((==k) . length) 
  . subsequences


OUTPUT:
*Main> maxSubProduct 3 [10,1,3,9,7,8,5]
[3,7,8]
```